# C# Reflection throws NullRefferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to get the data from a variable sent to the method as object, and I'm having the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The code:

```
public object SendNetworkData(object input, Classes.Macro Command)
{
    if (input is Classes.Authentication)
    {
        string Username = input.GetType().GetProperty("UserName").GetValue(input, null).ToString();
        string Password = input.GetType().GetProperty("Password").GetValue(input, null).ToString();

        Classes.Authentication InputAccount = new Classes.Authentication(Username, Password);

        return InputAccount;
    }
}
```

The problem arise at Line 5, and, as I am trying to debug, if I type input into watch, I get this:
         [Debug watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXjrj.png).

input contains those two members, but for some reason, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception. What can be the reason of this error?

Comment: You're trying to get property named "UserName". It should be "Username".

Comment: `GetProperty()` returns `null` if a (public) property with that name was not found in the object. So be sure that `UserName` is spelled correctly (case-sensitive!)

Comment: Yes, I changed from UserName to Username, but that still won't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, First you have a typo here: `GetProperty("UserName")`. The property is with lower `n` not capital.

Second, why not use casting?

```
var auth = input as Classes.Authentication;

if(auth != null )
{
    string Username = auth.Username;
    string Password = auth.Password;

    Classes.Authentication InputAccount = new Classes.Authentication(Username, Password);
}
```

But in any case why have a new `InputAccount`? Can't you use the casted `input` (now `auth`)?

Comment: Using casting resolved the issue! Thank you very much!

Comment: I used that to test if the input sent the correct information. I won't use it furthermore.

Comment: @SimaTudor Glad i could help. If this is the correct answer, Don't forget to accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers